# How to format a json feed from coldfusion to jquery fullcalendar?

Tags: json, coldfusion, fullcalendar

I am trying to get a json feed working for the jquery Full Calendar plugin but I am not having much luck.  The data I get back from coldfusion is not formatted correctly (at least that is my guess).  Here is what I am getting back:

```
{"COLUMNS":["TITLE","START","END","REQUEST_TYPE_ID"],"DATA":[["duration of a VTC ","2012-03-15T12:00:00Z","2012-03-15T15:00:00Z",1],["a new vtc overlap","2012-03-15T11:45:00Z","2012-03-15T14:15:00Z",1]]}
```

I am pretty sure full calendar does not know how to read this data type.  So the question is, can I get CF to pass back the data in a format that full calendar will accept?  Is there something else going on here?

Here is my component:

```
<cfquery datasource="#arguments.dsn#" name="eventlist">
select title, to_char(start_time,'YYYY-MM-DD')||'T'||to_char(start_time,'HH24:MI:SS')||'Z' as "start", 
to_char(start_time,'YYYY-MM-DD')||'T'||to_char(start_time + (duration/1440),'HH24:MI:SS')||'Z' as "end", request_type_id
from ((request r join event_schedule es on es.request_id = r.id)left join location_ref loc on loc.location_id = r.location_id) 
where site_id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
and request_type_id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.evnttype#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
and start_time between to_date('#sdate#', 'mon dd yyyy') and to_date('#edate#', 'mon dd yyyy')
</cfquery>
```

and the return format is json.

```
returnformat="json"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to format your data for the plugin to work. It needs to be an array of Event Objects http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

So you need to loop through your query and create an array of structs with the keys specified on the documentation in the above link.

You will need to use array notation as JavaScript is case-sensitive for variable names and CF likes to make the keys in structs uppercase by default.

So do this:-

```
<cfset myStruct["id"] = 1>
```

Instead of:-

```
<cfset myStruct.id = 1>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  That helps a lot.  However, I actually found a toJSON.cfc on [RIAforge](http://tojson.riaforge.org/) that did exactly what I needed.  For some reason I just have trouble with navigating json, and the thought of creating my own seemed a bit overwhelming.  Anyway, greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can just use SerializeJSON() or return the data from a cffunction with `returnformat='json'`

Comment: @Henry, not from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I created a CFC that returns jSon based on the date passed;
My CFC broken down:

```
<cfcomponent>
        <cffunction name="LoadCalendarData" access="remote" output="false" returntype="Any" returnformat="JSON">

            <cfargument name="DEPTID" type="any" required="false" />
            <cfargument name="STAFFCLASSID" type="any" required="false" />
            <cfargument name="start" type="date" required="false" />
            <cfargument name="end" type="date" required="false" />

            <cfset arguments.start=#DateFormat(DateAdd("s", arguments.start, "January 1 1970 00:00:00"), "mmmm dd, yyyy")#/>
            <cfset arguments.end=#DateFormat(DateAdd("s", arguments.end, "January 1 1970 00:00:00"), "mmmm dd, yyyy")#/>
<cfinvoke component="DataStore" method="Calendar_LU" returnvariable="qGetCalendar" DEPTID="#arguments.deptid#" STAFFCLASSID="#arguments.STAFFCLASSID#" START="#arguments.start#" END="#arguments.end#" />
```

I tranlate the arguments of the start date and end date in to something fullcalendar can use then I start to build by looping the data based on the information returned. next I break down the dates and times so I can pass it back to fullCalendar.

```
<cfset CalendarData=[] />       
    <cfset CalData = arraynew(2) />         
    <cfloop query="qGetCalendar">

    <cfset sd = #dateformat(LEAVESTARTDATE,'dd')# />
    <cfset sm = #dateformat(LEAVESTARTDATE,'mm')# />
    <cfset sy = #dateformat(LEAVESTARTDATE,'yyyy')# />
    <cfset sh = #timeformat(LEAVESTARTDATE,'HH')# />
    <cfset si = #timeformat(LEAVESTARTDATE,'mm')# />
    <cfset ed = #dateformat(LEAVEENDDATE,'dd')# />
    <cfset em = #dateformat(LEAVEENDDATE,'MM')# />
    <cfset ey = #dateformat(LEAVEENDDATE,'yyyy')# />
    <cfset eh = #timeformat(LEAVEENDDATE,'HH')# />
    <cfset ei = #timeformat(LEAVEENDDATE,'mm')# />
<cfset event=structNew() />
<cfset event['title']='#Left(ListLast(FULLNAME,","),1)#. #REReplace(ListFirst(FULLNAME,","),"'","")#' />
<cfset event['start']='#sy#-#sm#-#sd# #sh#:#si#' />
<cfset event['end']='#ey#-#em#-#ed# #eh#:#si#' />
<cfset event['textColor']='##330000'/>
<cfset event['backgroundColor']=STATUSColor />
<cfset event['url']=clickablePath />
<cfset arrayAppend(CalendarData,event)/>

</cfloop> 

    <cfreturn calendarData />
</cffunction>
```

in the script where fullCalendar is called I use this to call the CFC

```
eventSources: [{url:'CFCs/Holidays.cfc?Method=LoadCalendarHolidays'},{url:'CFCs/CalendarDataRemote.cfc?Method=LoadCalendarData&DEPTID=<cfoutput>#deptid#</cfoutput>&STAFFCLASSID=<cfoutput>#STAFFCLASSID#</cfoutput>'}],
```

As you can see I added another CFC call to pull in the our holidays so you can load more than one calendars data. Hope this helps

Comment: Nicely done and well document, thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure the keywords are lowercase... fullCalendar like javascript is case sensitive so you need start, end etc.

OOOPS just read the end of baynezy answer mentions this please disregard.

Comment: Thanks for the input either way.  You are correct, CF likes to put everything in UCASE and fullcalendar expects them to be in LCASE.